# In C++, 'Node' is a class, 'node' is the instance of 'Node'. Why " *node = nullptr " is wrong, but " *node = NULL" is correct？

Tags: c++, c++11

```
Node* node;    
*node = nullptr;
```

Report an error：

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
       *node = nullptr;
```

but

```
Node* node;    
*node = NULL;
```

is correct ?

Comment: Different isn’t the same. — Fred Picker.

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr

Comment: "`node` is the instance of `Node`" For some reason none of the answers seem to tell you clearly that this is incorrect. `node` is a *pointer* to `Node`.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely a `Node` can be constructed with an `int`. Since null is defined as an int constant equal to `0`, so you wrongly call the node constructor and assign it to the node.

As Sid S said, `node = nullptr` is the right expression.

Comment: `s/constructed/assigned/`

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` is most likely an old macro, inherited from the C world, and defined 0.

So what is happening in the second case is assigning the **number** 0 to a variable of type `Node`. Whereas in the first case a **pointer** (`nullptr`) is assigned.
The compiler knows for sure that this is wrong, since `*node` is not a pointer. Which means it will complain.

Whether it will complain for assigning a numeric 0 to `Node` will depend if the assignment operator for `Node` has been overloaded to accept a number. Or whether there is an implicit conversion/constructor from a number to `Node`.

Answer (score 3):

Neither one is correct. You should use `node = nullptr;` to assign to the `node` variable, as opposed to assigning to what `node` is pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

So:

```
Node* node;    
*node = nullptr;
```

cannot be done because, you are trying to assign pointer to type `Node`, what you should do is:

```
Node* node;    
node = nullptr;
```

You have to understand when you declare pointer you use following sintax:

```
int *n = 5;
n = nullptr;
```

where as following is

```
int *n = 5;
*n = 3;
```

`*n` is de-referencing pointer, and going to the address `n` points to. Same is true with in your `Node` example. Meanwhile `*node = NULL` might be implementation dependent. So `Node` type might have something like this:

```
Node& operator = (const Node &n ) { 
    if (n == NULL) {
        // do something
    }

    // do something else
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use node=nullptr;

You have made a pointer and now have to allocated the pointer to point to something, therefore node=nullptr;

Node * nullptr; defines the type of the variable nullptr is , it is a pointer to type node