# Data Structure -- C++ pointer pointing to itself

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I am new to C++. Originally a java developer

I created a binarytree in C++.
It added methods to add values and prints values .

But somewhere I have done some mistake and a pointer is pointing to itself in the printNode() method

I am pasting my code below.
Can anyone help me in figuring out the mistake I made

### **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <newbinarytree.cpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    NewBinaryTree* newtree;
    NewBinaryTree tree;
    newtree = &tree;
    newtree->add(10);
    newtree->add(11);
    newtree->add(7); **-->ALL goes well til here & debugger shows a proper tree**
    newtree->printTree();**--> This method does not print the tree values properly**

    return 0;
}
```

### **newbinarytree.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* left =NULL;
    Node* right =NULL;

    Node(int d){
        data = d;

    }
};

    class NewBinaryTree{
    private:
        Node* root = NULL;

    public:
        NewBinaryTree(){
            cout<<"Inside NewBinaryTree constructor";
        }

        void add(int dt){

            if(root ==NULL){
                Node node(dt);
                root = &node;
            }else{
                addAsChildOf(root,dt);
            }
        }

        void addAsChildOf(Node* tnode,int dt){
            if(dt < tnode->data){
                if(tnode->left == NULL){
                    Node newnode = Node(dt);
                    tnode->left = &newnode;
                }else{
                    addAsChildOf(tnode->left,dt);
                }
            }else{
                if(tnode->right == NULL){
                    Node newnode = Node(dt);
                    tnode->right = &newnode;
                }else{
                    addAsChildOf(tnode->right,dt);
                }
            }
        }

        void printTree(){
            if(root==NULL){
                cout<<"empty tree";
            }else{
                printNode(this->root);
            }
        }

        void printNode(Node* node1){ **--> This method goes into infinite loop**
            if(node1==NULL){
                return;
            }else{
                cout<<node1->data<<"[";

                if(node1->left != NULL){
                    cout<<"Left:";
                    printNode(node1->left);
                }
                if(node1->right != NULL){
                    cout<<"Right:";
                    printNode(node1->right);
                }
                cout<<"]";
            }
        }

    };
```

### **My Console output**

```
10[Left:4210843[]Right:2686564[Left:2686564
[Left:2686564[Left:2686564[Left:2686564[Left:2686564[Left:2686564[Left:2686564[Left:.... an so on
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Yes I tried, the left pointer in printNode() method is pointing to itself in 2nd recursion.. but I am not able to figure out where did I go wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `add` methods are faulty in `newbinarytree.cpp`. You're creating a temporary `Node` object which gets destructed automatically as the scope exits. This results in **undefined behaviour**, explaining why you're getting bogus values from your `printTree` method. (I think there is usually a warning that notifies you of creating temporary objects.) Here's how I'd modify your `add` method.

```
void add(int dt){
    if (root == NULL) {
        Node *node = new Node(dt);
        root = node;
    } else {
       addAsChildOf(root,dt);
    }
}
```

You should do the same with your `addAsChildOf` method as it uses the same, incorrect way of constructing and adding a new node.

To gain a better understanding of why your code doesn't work:

```
if (root == NULL) {
    Node node(dt);  //  construct Node object. All is well.
    root = &node;   //  set Node object. All is well.
}   //  end of scope. Node is destructed. Not well.
```

Additionally, please use [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) when setting pointers to a null pointer. Remember to also `delete` your dynamically-allocated Nodes to prevent memory leaks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. In fact I do have another code which used to create node the way you did above  and of course i loved it because this is how we do in java.. but i read comments that we need to delete it explicitly otherwise it might result in memory leaks.. also someone advised that new should be avoided in real time applications.. but as you pointed node will get destructed on scope exit

Comment: @RohitGaneshan "_i read comments that we need to delete it explicitly otherwise it might result in memory leaks_" Yes, you need to handle that with `new`. "_also someone advised that new should be avoided in real time application_" Right, generally `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are recommended over raw `new` and `delete`, but often `new` is used in practice when implementing trees or lists. Do look into `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.