# Loop Iteration in Pointer to Vector and Vector

Tags: c++

My code is,

```
//Pointer to a Vector
std::vector<int> *ptr =  new std::vector<int>;
ptr->push_back(20);
ptr->push_back(30);
ptr->push_back(40);
std::vector<int>::const_iterator pend = ptr->end();
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = ptr->begin(); it != pend;  ++it){
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}
ptr->clear();
delete ptr;
pend = ptr->end();
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = ptr->begin(); it != pend;  ++it){
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}


//Normal Vector
std::vector<int> nptr= {20,30,40};
std::vector<int>::const_iterator end = nptr.end();
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = nptr.begin(); it != end;  ++it){
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}
nptr.clear();
end = nptr.end();
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = nptr.begin(); it != end;  ++it){
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}
```

In the above sample code, I am iterating the pointer to vector and vector containers before and after clearing the container. In the normal vector case, the begin and end pointers are denoting the same element after done clear, it means the container is empty. In the pointer to a vector, the begin and end pointer never reset after using clear and delete the memory associated with the vector.

The output of the above code,

```
//pointer to vector before clear
20
30
40
//pointer to vector after clear
29006928
0
33
0
//vector before clear
20
30
40
//vector after clear
**no output**
```

Comment: What's your question? You `delete` the `ptr` and then you call `ptr->end()`, clearly that's undefined behavior.

Comment: My question is simple, why the loop is iterate after delete. Is delete is get back the memory associated with the vector?.

Comment: So your question is "Why does undefined behavior manifest in *this* way and not in *that* way"? The answer is "there is no telling what it's going to do". It could give no output, it could give any weird output imaginable, it could crash the program, or do anyhing else. There's no rule telling the compiler what it has to do in this case, so there's no point pondering why it's doing what it does. That's why people don't like undefined behavior; it's unreliable and non-portable.

Comment: There is a major difference between the two; the first clears *and destroys* the vector and then keeps using it (which is undefined since it doesn't exist), while the second only clears it.

Comment: please add the question from your comment to the question. Currently it is unclear what this quesiton is about by reading the question only

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it is :)

Answer (score 2):

when you call the `delete ptr;` you are de allocating the memory you reserved for the pointer object. And then you do `pend = ptr->end();` This will surely invoke undefined behavior because you don't have any `std::vector<int>` where you are pointing.

It is best practice to set the value of the pointer to **NULL** when you delete it. Because when you delete, you delete the object you point at not the content of the pointer. So the pointer is **STILL** pointing to the same memory location. When you set it to NULL in case if someone is trying to use that again, they would know that the pointer points to nothing.

```
ptr = nullptr;
```

Always keep in mind to do a NULL check before de-referencing a pointer

Comment: Please use nulltptr instead of NULL.

Comment: I have seen this. Any advantages using nullptr over NULL?

Comment: `NULL` is usually just `#define NULL 0`. `nullptr` is explicitly a null pointer and can only be assigned to pointer types. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr

Comment: NULL is only a fancy way to say 0. nullptr can't be assigned to int. You can assign it to bool but the usual conversion from bool to int doesn't work for nullptr.

Comment: Thanks! Editing the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you call `delete` on `ptr` you are destroying the `vector` and all of its elements.

Dereferencing (i.e. `*ptr` or `ptr->`) a deleted pointer is undefined behaviour.

When an object is deleted the memory it pointed to doesn't necessarily disappear (it might no longer be accessible if a whole memory page is no longer used) so dereferencing the pointer might not cause a crash. In your particular environment it looks like the memory isn't immediately overwritten (some environments will immediately overwrite deallocated memory, e.g. visual studio debug builds) enough of the vector's internal state is preserved that your loop manages to still print 4 values (probably the capacity of the vector before deletion). You can't rely on this behaviour though, it could print 0 values, 1000 values, crash or any other undefined behaviour.