# pass a pointer by reference in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo(int *&ptr) // pass pointer by reference
{
    ptr = nullptr; // this changes the actual ptr argument passed in, not a copy
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *ptr = &x;     // create a pointer variable ptr, which is initialize with the memory address of x; that is, ptr is a pointer which is pointing to int variable x
    std::cout << "ptr is: " << (ptr ? "non-null" : "null") << '\n'; // prints non-null
    foo(ptr);
    std::cout << "ptr is: " << (ptr ? "non-null" : "null") << '\n'; // prints null

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I understand it in the above code.

In the main function, firstly a local variable `x` is defined.
Then, a pointer variable with name `ptr` is defined, which is initialized with the memory address of `x`; i.e., `ptr` is a pointer variable which is pointing to the int variable `x`.
After that, check to see if `ptr` is null or not. Since it is initialized with a value, it is not-null?
After that, the function `foo` is called. Here, the parameter of the function `int *&ptr` can be understood as 
`int* &ptr`, i.e., this function foo accepts an `int*` (a pointer argument), and it is pass-by-reference because of the `&` in `int* &ptr`. Since it is pass-by-reference, the content of the pointer `ptr` is updated. So after the function call, the pointer variable `ptr` now has a value `nullptr`. That is why the very next `std::cout` would print null on the screen.

I hope I understand it correctly. An unrelated question: `null` is like nothing in C++, right? So `nullptr` is like a pointer which points to nothing?

Comment: `"null"` is just a string and your understanding of the code is correct.

Comment: @George the OP is not refering to a string but certainly asks about `null` and `nullptr`

Comment: You may be looking for this `c` declaration type:  `void foo(int **ptr){}`.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the code is correct. Sometimes it is easier to understand pointers to pointers and references of pointers, when you use aliases:

```
using int_ptr = int*;
void foo(int_ptr& ptr) // pass int_ptr by reference
{
    ptr = nullptr; // change the int_ptr that is referenced
}
```

This kind of an alias usually shouldn't be used in real code.

Regarding

> "null" is like nothing in C++, right? So nullptr is like a pointer which points to nothing?

Yes, `nullptr` by definition does not point to an object or a function (and therefore must not be dereferenced). `null` as a keyword does not exist in C++.
More info on null pointers in C++ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Null_pointers)

Comment: perhaps mention that such an alias would rather add confusion in real code (in this example it is a nice way to illustrate that pointers are no special)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding of the code is correct. Whenever you can, use analogy to simpler situations(like integers in your case) to understand things. A pointer is a variable which keeps a memory address. The null pointer concept means that a pointer points to nothing. You can find more about null concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr).

Comment: The linked SO thread does not actually explain what a null pointer is in C++. It just explains the C++11 definition of the `nullptr` keyword.

Comment: also there is no "null" only `nullptr`. As the question is about just that, your "You can find more about null here" can be confusing

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 talking about null as a concept is confusing to you?

Comment: your answer is confusing me, because null (value) does not exist as concept in c++ and your answer suggests the opposite