# Can I guarantee that the address of nullptr is always 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

I know that `NULL` is always `0`, but why does the following code print the message?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    if (ptr == 0) {
        cout << "Does it always work?";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"why does the following code print the message"* Why you don't expect it to?

Comment: "_I know that `NULL` is always `0`_" is incorrect.  On my platform, `NULL` is #define'd to be `__null`.

Comment: At the assembly level there is no difference. The difference is C++ type semantics.

Comment: @Eljay, according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49145382/6784796) "because NULL is 0", and I thought that NULL is defined as `#define NULL 0`

Comment: @catfour The phrase "because NULL is 0" doesn't mean NULL must be defined as `#define NULL 0`. It's a bit simplified anyway.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, But I see many people initialize the pointers with `0`'s instead of `NULL` and it works well (before `nullptr`). Could you please give more details about your point of view?

Comment: @catfour It's not my point of view, but a basic fact about the language. C++ provides _conversions_. (e.g. `1` can become `true`). That does not mean that the macro `NULL` is defined as `#define NULL 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

A pointer initialised from `nullptr` is a null pointer.

Comparing a null pointer to the literal `0` (or to a `std::nullptr_t`, which `nullptr` is; together these are *null pointer constants*) yields `true`, always.

- http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#14
- http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#1

You can't do this with any old expression, though; even if integer `i` is 1, `i-i` is not a valid null pointer constant, despite evaluating to 0 at runtime. Your 
program will not compile if you try to do this. Only the *literal* `0` is a valid null pointer constant that can be compared to pointers.

Also, that does not necessarily mean that it has all bits zero, though! Much like how converting a `bool` to `int` gives you zero or one, but the actual underlying bits of the `bool` can be whatever the implementation likes.

Finally, note that your terminology is slightly off; per [`[support.types.nullptr/1]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.types.nullptr#1), `nullptr` itself has no address that can be taken

Comment: So, it doesn't matter if I initialized an array of pointers with zeros `memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr)` instead of `arr[i]=nullptr` in a `for` loop, right?

Comment: @catfour No `memset` is not safe. This answer already says that: "*that does not necessarily mean that it has all bits zero, though!*". You should avoid using `memset` at all in C++. Use `std::fill` instead, if you don't want to write loops.

Comment: @walnut OK thank you, but I disagree with "You should avoid using `memset` at all in C++. Use `std::fill` instead" because `memset` is faster than `std::fill` and we can initialize the array with `0` or `-1` safely using `memset` (it's very useful in competitive programming).

Comment: @catfour Compilers dispatch `std::fill` calls to `memset` calls if that is possible (i.e. for trivially-copyable types): https://godbolt.org/z/q8-qMF The benefit of `std::fill` is that it works for *every* type, not only trivially-copyable ones, and is type-safe. Performance is generally not a good reason to use `memset`.

Comment: @catfour `memset` is not faster than `std::fill`. `std::fill` will invoke `memset` if it can. It's a zero-cost wrapper that gives you type safety and more features where needed. This "competitive programming" just seems to be a race to make the worst code the fastest. Well done, I guess...‍♂️

Comment: @catfour In fact, this is a good example, because with your `memset` you are just zeroing bytes. If "null pointer" is not represented that way on your platform, your program is broken. `std::fill`, being typesafe, will do it properly (with any necessary conversions). Admittedly in that instance you probably don't get the `memset` "optimisation" but that's because it wouldn't work (as previously mentioned).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings OK, thank you for this information. Isn't `memset` faster with the optimization level `-O2`?

Comment: @catfour: It's possible that with optimisations _turned off_, function call overhead in the wrapper comes into play. But comparing performance in the "no optimisation" mode is a fool's errand (no offence). With `-O2`, I can't imagine _any_ difference.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I will not use useless wrappers to the function I want to call just for the sake of it.