# reversing the linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

node *head=NULL;

void print(struct node*)
{
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

struct node* insert(struct node* head,int x)
{
    node *temp=new node();
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    return head;
}

struct node* reverse(struct node* head)
{
    node *current,*next,*prev;
    current=head;
    prev=NULL;
    next=NULL;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        next=current->next;
        current->next=prev;
        current=next;
        prev=current;
    }
    head=prev;
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head=NULL;
    head=insert(head,2);
    head=insert(head,4);
    head=insert(head,3);
    head=insert(head,8);
    print(head);
    head=reverse(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;

}
```

**Can someone point out what is wrong with this code.I have tried executing it but I seem to be having a problem with printing. And even after I try making correction, it is only printing the linked list and not the reverse linked list.
I am a beginner.Thank you.**

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing the code does incorrectly?

Comment: This looks like a C linked list. This is a terrible way to do a linked list in C++. Reversing would be trivial if the list was doubly linked.

Comment: There are many wrong things with it. To start, you're not using the parameter variables. The `head` in the global scope is always NULL, etc.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to run your program one line at a time, specifically in the `reverse()` function, and see, exactly, line by line, which pointers get set to which values, and what goes wrong? Your debugger should be able to make the problem very clear.

Comment: One of the best ways, if not the best, to understand linked lists is to visualize the problem by drawing pictures. Draw a lot of pictures. If you draw the state of the list step by step as you perform an operation on it you can eliminate most errors before you start coding, and if you still get errors, you can step through the program on paper or with a debugger and compare the results against your drawings.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

Your code has many things to fix, but pointing specifically to your question the problem is in the print function.

There are 2 problems for your question:

1. You're using a global variable called `head` that is always NULL instead of using the one that is passed as parameter.
2. Reverse function is incorrect.

**Solution**

Change this

```cpp
node *head=NULL;

void print(struct node*)
{
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

For this:

```cpp
void print(struct node* head)
{
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

In this way you will be using the node in the parameter instead of the node in global scope that is always NULL.

In reverse function change:

```cpp
current = next;
prev = current;
```

For this:

```cpp
prev = current;
current = next;
```

**Additional information:**

1. `using namespace std;` is a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).
2. You should probably add a class to wrap the linked list with the methods.
3. I would use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` to avoid confusions (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)).
4. Maybe you should search a [good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include<iostream>

struct node{
public:
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class linkedList
{
private:
    node* head;
public:
    linkedList();
    void print();
    void reverse();
    void insert(int);
    void invert();
};

linkedList::linkedList()
{
    head = nullptr;
}

void linkedList::print()
{
    node *temp = this->head;
    while(temp!=nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void linkedList::insert(int x)
{
    node *temp = new node();
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = this->head;
    this->head = temp;
}

void linkedList::reverse()
{
    node *current,*next,*prev;
    current = this->head;
    prev = nullptr;
    next = nullptr;
    while(current != nullptr)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next=prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    this->head = prev;
}

int main()
{
    linkedList myList;
    myList.insert(4);
    myList.insert(4);
    myList.insert(3);
    myList.insert(8);
    myList.print();
    myList.reverse();
    myList.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `head=insert(head,2);` leaves `head` as NULL? This answer looks wrong to me. The real bug appears to be somewhere else, entirely.

Comment: That `head` is a local variable in `int main()` which is yet another `head` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your `print` as others have mentioned.

Your `reverse` is incorrect.

In `reverse`, you have:

```
current = next;
prev = current;
```

`prev` will be `NULL` on the first iteration [which is correct]. But, afterwards, it won't be the previous node, but, just the same as the current node.

You want:

```
prev = current;
current = next;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is less of a direct answer to what's plaguing your code and more of a look at what a "proper" C++ solution could look like. It utilizes a doubly-linked list, meaning the Nodes know what previous AND next Nodes in the list are. I did this because a function like `reverse()` becomes exponentially easier.

*Tangent*
Students are often given the option of writing a doubly linked list and skip it, not realizing how much easier it makes their lives, and the only cost is a few more pointer assignments. That's my class, anyway.
*/Tangent*

C++ is its own language from C. That becomes the case more and more every time a new C++ standard is released. This C method with a global Node and free functions is just horrible C++.

Below is an example of how a C++ linked list could look. This is quick code and shouldn't be considered definitive at all. I use a class, and encapsulate everything about a linked list into that class. I have some comments explaining some code choices (or lack thereof).

I chose not to use smart pointers, because to me they don't make a lot of sense in a data structure. That's a very subjective opinion.

I am also not taking advantage of any C++20 features; I just don't know them well enough yet.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// Ideally all of this linked list code would be in its own header file that
// you include in your main.cpp
template <typename T>
class LinkedList;

template <typename T>
void print(LinkedList<T>& list);

template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
 public:
  LinkedList() = default;
  ~LinkedList();

  // I am ommitting the remainder of the Rule of 0/3/5 functions which are
  // required if you want the list to function properly. It is much simpler
  // to implment them using the copy/swap idiom
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/6119582

  void push_back(T val);  // for C++ insert() usually means at any position
  void reverse();

  // Added for simplicity. The real way would be to ensure T can be printed
  // (operator<<() for custom T) and provide iterators for the LinkedList.
  // Worth noting that because I didn't want to implement the full Rule of
  // 0/3/5, that this function is less than ideal, but it exists only to
  // demonstrate that the list is behaving.
  friend void print<T>(LinkedList& list);

 private:
  struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next = nullptr;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
  };

  Node* m_head = nullptr;
  Node* m_tail = nullptr;
};

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
  Node* tmp = m_head;
  while (tmp) {
    m_head = m_head->next;
    delete tmp;
    tmp = m_head;
  }
  m_tail = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(T val) {
  // Empty list
  if (!m_head) {
    m_head = new Node{val};
    m_tail = m_head;
    return;
  }

  m_tail->next = new Node{val};
  m_tail->next->prev = m_tail;
  m_tail = m_tail->next;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::reverse() {
  // We start at the end of the list, and simply swap the next and prev
  // pointers. And we do that for every Node in the list, finally, we swap the
  // LinkedList's head and tail pointers. This is a lot tougher in a singly-
  // linked list.
  Node* walker = m_tail;
  while (walker) {
    std::swap(walker->next, walker->prev);
    walker = walker->next;
  }
  std::swap(m_head, m_tail);
}

template <typename T>
void print(LinkedList<T>& list) {
  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* tmp = list.m_head;
  while (tmp) {
    std::cout << tmp->data << ' ';
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  LinkedList<int> list;

  for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
    list.push_back(i);
  }
  print(list);
  list.reverse();
  print(list);
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

As you can see, actually writing C++ for a linked list is **very** different from writing a linked list in C. It's unfortunate that your class has not evolved in at least a decade.

It's also worth saying that if the class were to be fully implemented (iterators and other stuff I said was missing), the main function would look so much better and allow our list to be used by more of the Standard Library.