# How to properly return null/empty object in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a Java developer trying to solve a simple C++ task. In Java, if I want to return an empty/null object, to indicate that object is not found I just return null. Example:

```java
Person getGetByName(String name) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (people[i].name == name) {
            return people[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

later in code I can do

```java
Person p = getByName("Sam");

if (p == null) { ...
}
```

In C++ I have the following method

It seems that if I declare a method like the above, returning NULL is not an option since the method doesn't return a pointer but rather a class.
So what do I return to indicate that no person is found ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr . C++ has nullptr

Comment: Use `std::optional` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Comment: You should maybe not tag the question with [tag:java]. Sure, you mention Java for context, but apart from that this is a C++ question, not a Java one.

Comment: Java programmers have learned many things that work differently in C++. This is one of them. Java returns **references** (which in C++ are pointers) to objects; C++ returns objects. C++ doesn't have null objects. It has null pointers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++17 or above, use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Alternatively, return a value that would convey a similar meaning, e.g. a `std::pair<bool, Person>` Note that this would still require a `Person` object to be there, it merely does not need to be valid. If the objects are too large to be returned emptily like that, you'll have to find a workaround, like a union, or a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

There's one more problem to the above code - the C++ version is inefficient. In C++, returning `Person` *by-value* always returns a *copy* of it (except for RVO, which is not applicable here).

Unlike C++, Java has no value semantics for objects, in Java returning `Person` always returns a *reference* to an object. A reference in Java works more like a *pointer* in C++, e.g. it can be `null`.

So the equivalent C++ code would actually be:

```
Person* getGetByName(std::string const& name) {
  for(int i = 0 ;i<10 ;i++) { 
    if(people[i].name == name){
      return &people[i]; 
    }  
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

Now you can do

```
Person* p = getGetByName("blah");
if (p == nullptr) {
  // not found ...
} else {
  // use p->name etc.
}
```

C++ has no automatic memory management. The lifetime of the `people` vector must thus outlast the returned pointer. If that's not the case then it's more idiomatic to work with smart pointers instead (e.g. `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`). Thinking about object lifetimes is the responsibility of the C++ developer.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the person object through a parameter and return a `bool` to indicate if something meaningful was returned through the parameter:

```cpp
bool getGetByName(const std::string& name, Person& person)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)
  { 
    if(people[i].name == name)
    {
      person = person[i]     // Writing in the person param (note the reference in the definition of the 'person' parameter).
      return true;           // Indicate success (i.e. non null).
    }
  }  

  return false;              // Indicates null.
}
```

Later in code you could write:

```cpp
Person aPerson;
if(getGetByName("A name", aPerson))
{
  // aPerson is valid, do something with it.
}

// aPerson is not valid, handle it.
```

Comment: C++17 has [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). `Person*` is also an option here.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, class instance variables and such returned objects are actually references/pointers. Since they are pointers, they can point to null. Primitive types such as `int` on the other hand are not pointers. Since they aren't pointers, they cannot point to null. You cannot have `int x = null;`.

In C++, class instance variables and such returned objects are not pointers. Like the Java primitives, they cannot point to null.

> How to properly return null/empty object in C++?

If the type of the object has a value that represents null or empty, then simply return that value. Here is an example where that type is a pointer:

```
int* function()
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

When a type has an empty value, such value can usually (but not necessarily) be created using value initialisation. Here is an example that returns an empty vector:

```
std::vector<int> function()
{
    return {};
}
```

If the type doesn't have a representation for null or empty, then you cannot return a null or empty value that doesn't exist.

However, using type erasure techniques, it is possible to design a class that internally contains either a value of another type, or doesn't. Using a template, such class can be used to augment any type with an empty value. The standard library comes with such template: `std::optional`.

---

As for your particular example, idiomatic solution in C++ is to return an iterator to the found element, and return an iterator to the (one past the) end of the range if nothing is found. Iterator is a generalisation of a pointer. Your example re-written in C++:

```
auto getGetByName(std::string_view name) {
    auto first = std::begin(people);
    auto last  = std::end(people);
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == name) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}

// later

auto it = getByName("Sam");
if (it == std::end(people)) { ...
}
```

Note that there is no need to write that function, since the C++ standard library provides implementation of linear search. Simply call:

```
auto it = std::ranges::find(people, "Sam");
```