# What does * when using nullptr mean?

Tags: c++

what does the * mean in

```
int* p = nullptr;
```

Also, it would be helpful if anyone can example what nullptr means. Is it equivalent to null? Sorry, I recently started learning c++;

Comment: `int *` here declares a pointer-to-an-int type.  So `p` will be a pointer to an int.

Comment: `nullptr` is a constant that is pretty much the same thing as NULL.

Comment: In that case I would recommend our curated list of [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If I said "nullptr" is a null pointer, would that make sense to you or not?

Comment: Definitely get a few good books. It'll speed your learning time enormously. C++ is a hard language to master without a good guide, and it doesn't reward trial and error very often.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [What exactly is nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)

Comment: SO isn't a good place for learning like this. Please find a good book and learn from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does the * mean in
>
> int* p = nullptr;

`*` refers to a pointer-to-an object which holds a specific location/address in memory, in your case it is a pointer-to-an-int and so it refers to the address of an integer.

> Also, it would be helpful if anyone can example what nullptr means. Is it equivalent to null? Sorry, I recently started learning c++;

Both `NULL` and `nullptr` point to the zeroth address (0x000000) in memory.

In most cases, the C++11 keyword [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) is ***similar*** to [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) in the sense that they usually point to the same thing. But, there are some subtle differences between the two:

```cpp
decltype(NULL);    /* 'void*' or `intptr_t`, depends on implementation, the former is
                    * an object pointer type while the latter is just an integer that
                    * can hold an address */
decltype(nullptr); // Always 'std::nullptr_t'
```

From this, we find that `nullptr` is in fact, not a pointer but an *instance of a class*, `std::nullptr_t`.

Essentially, [`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) is a wrapper class which *indirectly* refers to the zeroth address in memory. All instances of this class (including `nullptr`) are implicitly convertible to the pointer of any type.

The reason for this sort of design was to facilitate function overloading, so that `nullptr` could have a consistent type that could be safely overloaded, unlike `NULL` which does not have a consistent type across different implementations:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

void f(long int) {
    std::cout << "Encountered a long" << std::endl;
}

void f(decltype(NULL)) {
    std::cout << "Encountered NULL" << std::endl;
}

void f(decltype(nullptr)) {
    std::cout << "Encountered nullptr" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(0l);
    f(NULL);
    f(nullptr);
}
```

In this case, normally, one would think that this would output:

```
Encountered a long
Encountered NULL
Encountered nullptr
```

But it gets more complicated than this, on certain implementations, the compiler would give this error:

```
// Output from the GCC compiler:
source>:8:6: error: redefinition of 'void f(long int)'
    8 | void f(decltype(NULL)) {
      |      ^
```

This is because `decltype(NULL)` is `long int` in *this case* (not always), which causes the overload `void f(long int)` to be defined twice, leading to a compilation error.

This is one of the use cases of `nullptr`. It safely retains its type, which is `std::nullptr_t`.

In contrast, `NULL` doesn't have any defined universal type, so it can't be safely overloaded in a function based on its type.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, it will be easy if you consider `*` as "value at address" operator. Its counterpart `&` is "address of" operator. Now let's see how to interpret this:

```
int* p = nullptr;
```

One can read this as "Value at address stored in `p` is an `int` and that address is initialized with `nullptr`".

Before C++/11, we used to assign `0` or `NULL` to it. `NULL` is also defined as `0`. But it could be confused with number `0` that is why `nullptr` was introduced. It is equivalent of `null` in other languages. For details See: [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)

Comment: A good example of how the problem discussed here lingers is `std::string temp(0);`, sometime used by folk trying into convert an integer to a string. If you use any number other than zero, it won't compile. But with 0 it compiles and crashes the program because the compiler interpreted the 0 as a pointer to a null-terminated character array at address 0 and calls the `const char *` `string` constructor. Really sucks.

Comment: That is related but a complete different topic in itself. Let me give you another even more interesting example. `int arr[3]={1,2,3};` and then try to print `1[arr]`. But these are just wordplay once you get a grasp over language. I think C/C++ should not be taken as other RAD languages. One should study it before jumping to start working on it.

Comment: More fun/on topic example: `NULL[arr]` -> https://ideone.com/suEh5H

Comment: In my experience, there's a lot of confusion from novices out there when they think of `int*` as having an operator `*` in it. It's looked best to fully differentiate `*` and `&` when used in types vs. their use as operators in expressions rather than conflate the two and leave novices to not realize that `*` has two completely different meanings that are both related to pointers. (Aside, as C declaration syntax is modelled after expressions, it makes sense to use the expression counterparts _for reading declarations_, but not for explaining how to use pointers in general.)

Comment: @user4581301 

Comment: @chris yes, some people might find that approach simpler but that just because different people understand things differently.

Answer (score -3):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/nullptr-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-nullptr-c/) should be helpful

It's basically used to indicate an object handle, interior pointer, or native pointer type does not point to an object.

int* p = nullptr means the integer pointer that doesn't point to an integer variable

Comment: No, I added another link from gfg also

Comment: All to often a link to gfg earns scorn because the site has limited, if any, curation. And when the first code example starts with a pair lines famed for their ability to produce whacky errors ([Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721)) we're off to a really bad start. Fortunately, once it gets past that opening bit of idiocy, it's not too bad. No downvote today.