# How head and tail is connected in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I got this code from chat GPT.Can anyone explain me..How head and tail is connected in above code,because i am unable to understand that how address of tail is passed to head.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL; // Initialize the head pointer to null
    Node *tail = NULL; // Initialize the tail pointer to null

    // Create a loop to add new nodes to the linked list
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Node *newNode = new Node(); // Create a new node object
        newNode->data = i;          // Set the data variable for the new node
        newNode->next = NULL;       // Set the next pointer to null

        // If the list is empty, set the head and tail pointers to the new node
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        // Otherwise, add the new node to the end of the list and update the tail pointer
        else
        {
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    // Print out the linked list
    Node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->data << " ";
        current = current->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it step by step. In the first node-addition, when the list is empty, both "head" and "tail" are updated. In the rest of cases only previous "tail->next" must be updated and then the "tail" itself must point to the freshly created newNode.

Comment: If ChatGPT wrote it, perhaps ChatGPT can explain it.

Comment: Don't use ChatGPT. Don't use [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Don't use `NULL`, use [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

`head` and `tail` are connected through the inner elements.

At the start, they are both `NULL`, although it is better to use `nullptr`.

When the first node is added, both point to it. After that. tail will always point to the last element and `head` to the first.

| action | state after |
| --- | --- |
| start | `head` = `tail` = `NULL` |
| first insert | `head` = `tail` = new node -> `NULL` |
| second insert | `head` = first node -> `tail` = second node -> `NULL` |
| third insert | `head` = first node -> second node -> `tail` = third node -> `NULL` |

Here, the convencion `->` means to where the `next` field of the node point to. The equals sign, is to say what is the value of `head` and `tail` in each state.

Comment: @SameeUllahJafar, you're welcome, if this really helps you, please accept the answer or up vote it, so others know it is useful.