# Template class method syntax

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

In the following example:

```
template<class Foo>
struct FooBar 
{
   FooBar(Foo *pObj = 0) : pFoo_(pObj) {}
};
```

what does "*pObj = 0" mean?

Comment: So basically pObj is set to NULL prior to being used?

Comment: IIRC, it means that it will default to NULL if nothing is passed in.

Comment: @Sebi: If you don't pass any parameters to the constructor then it will use `0` (aka null pointer) as the value of `pObj`. Note this has nothing to do with templates it is just normal C++ syntax for automatic parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the default value of `pObj`, if the caller doesn't provide one, is `0`. In this particular case, it would have been better form to use `NULL` (which is usually a macro of `0`). There are now two ways of calling it:

```
FooBar fb = FooBar(); //pObj is NULL
FooBar fb2 = FooBar(someFoo); //pObj is someFoo
```

Comment: NULL cannot be a macro for `(void*)0` in C++, because the compiler will refuse to implicitly cast `void*` into another pointer type, unlike in C.

Comment: `FooBar fb();` is not null but `fb` is function

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Fixed most vexing parse issue.

Comment: Personally I prefer using `NULL`. But I don't think it is bad form to use `0` (but I will move to `nullptr` when it get here). Further reading: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/176989/14065), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1296843/14065) and [here](http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html) links doug up by [Konrad](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/308/konrad-rudolph) on a question we were discussing [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/13062/507)

Comment: @LokiAstari: Thanks for the links. I just think that `NULL` can be a little clearer because it makes it clear that you are working with pointers in an intentional way -- not just creating buckets of segfaults.

Comment: @Linuxios: I totally agree with you. Personally I think NULL is preferable. But I would not go all the way to say that all the C++ community agrees with me/you, this is one of those debated topics (whose outcome I don't care about as nullptr is coming).

Comment: And note that, despite the title, this is not about templates. The same thing applies to non-template functions: `void f(int i = 0);' declares a function that takes one argument of type `int` and returns `void`. It can be called with no arguments; in that case, the value 0 is passed as the argument.

Comment: @pete I have ran across this example in a template context. Anyway thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Sebi - I don't know what you're referring to. I didn't downvote. I just commented that this applies in a much broader context.