# What is an elegant solution to this error from std::find?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std

I have a class which contains an array which size is unknown at compile time. The array is initialized in the constructor. Then, I have another function that checks if an element is in the array:

```
class myClass
{
   int tab[];
  public:
   myClass(int array[], int length)
   {  
      std::copy(array, array + length, tab)
   }
   void myFunction()
   {
      int x = 8;
      int *ptr = std::find(std::begin(tab), std::end(tab), tdc_x);
      if (ptr) /* here goes my code */
   }
};
```

I got the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int [0])’

What's wrong with the above piece of code? I know that I can't use std::find with pointers, but my array is an array, not a decayed pointer.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215027/check-if-element-found-in-array-c) example. I also included the *algorithm* header. What am I doing wrong?

I compile my code in C++11.

**Edit:** I get it now. But how can I do what I want to do in an elegant way?

> 1. If I use a pointer instead of the empty array, I won't be able to use std::find.
> 2. if I give my array an arbitrary size, I won't be able to copy a bigger array. 
>      What should I do?

Comment: `int tab[];` You cannot have empty arrays.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, my array isn't empty, it hasn't been initialised yet. The compiler doesn't complain about that. Could you suggest an alternative solution to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Where did you initialize it?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, in the constructor.

Comment: `std::copy()` doesn't magically allocate memory for you.

Comment: `int tab[];` defines an empty array (an array of 0 elements). Such arrays are not allowed by C++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int tab[];
```

The standard doesn't allow empty arrays, but some compilers do as an extension. That doesn't make it legit tho.

> If I use a pointer instead of the empty array, I won't be able to use std::find.

Not true, you can still use `std::find` (`s` is the size of your tab array).

```
  int *ptr = std::find(tab, tab + s, tdc_x);
```

> if I give my array an arbitrary size, I won't be able to copy a bigger array. What should I do?

Use a `std::vector<int>`, then call `resize()`