# Is it possible to write an in_array helper function using std library's find, begin and end?

Tags: c++

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19215059/9289878) on SO which explains how to perform a search for a value in an array. Coming from a PHP background, I am used to a degree of dynamic typization - something not present in C++, which then poses several challenges. Would it be then possible to create a helper function that would perform analogous to PHP's `in_array($needle, $haystack)` (for example, using the code from the linked answer) to be used as a shorthand?

Having written this snippet, I understand (tangibly) why it doesn't work - the parameters don't really have types signified. What, if anything, could be done to circumvent this, and would it be bad practice to do so?

```
bool in_array(needle, haystack) {
    // Check that type of needle matches type of array elements, then on check pass:
    pointer* = std::find(std::begin(haystack), std::end(haystack), needle);
    return pointer != std::end(haystack);
}
```

**Edit:** To be extra clear, I don't really want to PHPize C++ - what I was looking for is a way it's usually done in C++!

Comment: C++ is statically typed; You may want to use std::any to simulate PHP but the proper procedure is to get familiar with static types.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, actually! Matter of fact, if there's a way to do this with static types, I would absolutely love that, because the only idea I have so far is just making an in_array function for each type I might need it for.

Comment: In C++ we use templates to avoid rewriting a function for each type.

Comment: Trying to get one language to work like another is typically the first mistake, when learning a new one. C++ will not treat you well until you start leaning into its strengths. Forget about duck-typing, and start over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what templates are for:

```
template <class ValueType, class Container>
bool in_array(const ValueType& needle, const Container& haystack) {
// Check that type of needle matches type of array elements, then on check pass:
    return std::find(std::begin(haystack), std::end(haystack), needle) != std::end(haystack);
}
```

Provided that `Container` type is either a C-style array or it has accessible member methods `begin()` and `end()`; and that `ValueType` is convertible to `Container::value_type`, this should work.

---

This being said, templates are not an easy topic to handle. If you want to learn more, I recommend you one of [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: There doesn't need to be an `std::begin` and `std::end` for `Container`. If it has `begin()` and `end()` member functions, which any sane container type will have, `std::begin` and `std::end` will work.

Comment: @NikosC. Well, if the container has those member functions, then there is `std::begin` and `std::end` for the container. That's why they work.

Comment: @eerorika That's not correct. If you define your own container type, there is no `std::begin` overload or specialization for it. But it will work fine if your custom container has a `begin()` member function.

Comment: @NikosC. There is an overload for the container. The specific template overload that returns `c.begin()`.

Comment: @Nicos Yes, I couldn't find the right wording to name it. C-style array has it's overloads, but for others it relies on existance of `begin()` and `end()` member methods. If you have better proposition, feel free to edit or suggest it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Templates let you write the function

```
template <class T, class U, size_t N>
bool in_array(const T& needle, U (&haystack)[N]) {
    // Check that type of needle matches type of array elements, then on check pass:
    return std::find(std::begin(haystack), std::end(haystack), needle) != std::end(haystack);
}
```

But I'm not really sure what this gets you, it's still statically typed. Static typing is a good thing of course.

Untested code.

Comment: @sp2danny Yes, but that was the question I think. Obviously the OP should be using proper C++ instead of trying to make C++ like PHP, but I'm just answering the question. I expect they'll realise the benefits of C++ soon enough.