# Strange behavior with null pointers

Tags: c++

I have stumbled upon the following problem, if I compile (using Visual Studio 2010)

```
int main()
{
    double* d_ptr = int(0);
    if(d_ptr == nullptr)
         cout << "I am a nullptr" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the result "I am a nullptr"

This also works if I substitute the pointer assignment with:

```
double* ptr = (int) 0;
```

I would have expected both to fail since they both explicitly cast to integer which has not a pointer type. Could someone help me in understanding what is going on?

EDIT: Tried again with g++ and worked. Do not know what I did wrong the first time. Now I am only still troubled why it works in the first place.

Comment: Could you include the error message from `g++` please ?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a4516f5d3e9750e) with g++.

Comment: @NathanOliver clang says ["cannot initialize a variable of type 'double *' with an rvalue of type 'int'"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad432ad2fb0412cb), though.

Comment: "I would have expected both to fail." why?

Comment: Please check out [Do you use NULL or 0 (zero) for pointers in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wandered into one of the murkier areas of C++ (and C).  Quoting from [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (which is the latest freely available draft of C++14):

> 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]
>
> 1 A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.
>   A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type

I am *slightly* surprised that `(int)0` is accepted as "an integer literal" - in fact, I think that is a bug in the compiler (but it is very much a corner case).

Ah-ha!  I have just remembered:  Older versions of C and C++ didn't say "integer literal", they said "integer constant expression".  `int(0)` *is* an integer constant expression, so it is allowed on older compilers.

This means your problem with g++ could depend on whether you specified C++14 or an earlier version.

Comment: I believe enforcing `(int) 0` to fail would possibly break way too match existing code.

Comment: @Slava: You think so?  Most people write `NULL` or `0` - not `(int)0`.  The cast is pointless as `0` is already of type int.

Comment: @MartinBonner (int)0 or other expressions used to be legal in old C++ standard. Restricting it may break working code anyway.

Comment: @DieterLücking: I don't *think* it should.  That looks like a bug to me - but I could easily be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

By assigning the value of `0`, to the pointer, you are setting it to null, so it is a `nullptr`. To make the pointer have the value of 0, do this:

```
double * dbl = new double{0};
```