# How do I initiliaze a head in a doubly-linked list to be NULL?

Tags: c++

I have a homework to implement a doubly-linked list in C++ with two structs. One of them should hold the **next and previous pointers**, as well as the data. The other struct should hold two pointers, one for the head and one for the tail

```
Struct DlistElem{
    int data;
    DlistElem* next;
    DlistElem* prev;
  }

Struct Dlist{
 Dlist * head;
 Dlist * tail;
}

//some functions
```

the problem I'm having is I don't know how to initialize both the head and tail to be null in order to use them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is wrong with assigning `NULL` to each?

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for the answer. I'm quite new to C++ so I didn't know if this was allowed :)

Comment: Usually, the best choice for C++ is  nullptr , a literal since C++11.

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/177007/2785528

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the pointers with NULL when you create a DlistElem and Dlist.

```
struct DlistElem{
    DlistElem* prev;
    DlistElem* next;
    int data;
    DlistElem() :
        prev(NULL),
        next(NULL),
        data()
    {}
}

struct Dlist{
    Dlist* head;
    Dlist* tail;
    Dlist() :
        head(NULL),
        tail(NULL)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to initialize both the head and tail to be null in order to use them.

```
struct DlistElem {
    int data;
    DlistElem* next;
    DlistElem* prev;

    DlistElem() : data{}, next{}, prev{}
    {}
};
```

or

```
struct DlistElem {
    int data;
    DlistElem* next{};
    DlistElem* prev{};
};
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is, how do I later on access it some methods ?

Comment: @TonislavTachev What is "on access it some methods ?" ?

Comment: @TonislavTachev The same way you access all other struct members? Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Since I want to use the head in let's say an InsertAtFirst() method, where I first check if the head is null, afterwards if it is I'll proceed to add a new node. But I'm getting an error message, saying that head wasn't defined in this scope

Comment: @TonislavTachev comments are not for questions. if you have another question, go and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way this can be done in c++11 is:

```
struct DlistElem{
    int data;
    DlistElem* next = nullptr;
    DlistElem* prev = nullptr;
}

struct Dlist{
    Dlist * head = nullptr;
    Dlist * tail = nullptr;
}
```